# Extract all characters before a period with HiveQL regex?

Tags: sql, regex, hive, hiveql

I have a table that looks like:

```
bl.ah
foo.bar
bar.fight
```

And I'd like to use HiveQL's `regexp_extract` to return

```
bl
foo
bar
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the [docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) data about **regexp_extract**:

`regexp_extract(string subject, string pattern, int index)`

> Returns the string extracted using the pattern. For example, regexp_extract('foothebar', 'foo(.*?)(bar)', 2) returns 'bar.' Note that some care is necessary in using predefined character classes: using '\s' as the second argument will match the letter s; '\s' is necessary to match whitespace, etc. The 'index' parameter is the Java regex Matcher group() method index. See docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html for more information on the 'index' or Java regex group() method.

So, if you have a table with a single column (let's call it `description` for our example) you should be able to use regexp_extract as follows to get the data *before* a period, if one exists, or the entire string in the absence of a period:

```
regexp_extract(description,'^([^\.]+)\.?',1)
```

The components of the regex are as follows:

- `^` start of string
- `([^\.]+)` any non-period character one or more times, in a capture group
- `\.?` a period either once or no times

Because the part of the string we're interested in will be in the first (and only) capture group, we refer to it by passing the `index` parameter a value of *1*.

Comment: This returns everything after the period; not before

Comment: Oops.  My answer has been updated to get text before the period.

Comment: How would we adjust the query to get all the characters after the period?

Comment: To get the characters after the period: `regexp_extract(description,'\.?([^\.]+)$',1)`

If you view the history of the question, my original answer describes this approach in more detail (I'd misinterpreted what Danny was asking for)